# Unable to define range of values for ports

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My goal is to have multiple ports defined for a service of type `LoadBalancer` and I do not want to copy paste the same thing over and over again.

I did come to a solution, but sure how I could define the range - I need all values from 50000 to 50999.

In my service, I define the range:

```
{{- range $service.ports }}
  - name: tport
    protocol: TCP
    port: {{ . }}
  {{- end }}
```

And in my values file:

```
ports: 
  - 50000
  - 50001
  - 50999
```

How could I define the ports or update the service template to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the min and max port as two different values on your values.yaml and use the range on your template like this:

```
{{- range untilStep (.Values.config.min_port|int) (.Values.config.max_port|int) 1 }}
- port: {{ . }}
  targetPort: "tcp-{{ . }}"
  protocol: TCP
  name: "tcp-{{ . }}"
{{ -end }}
```

Comment: can the targetPort be tcp-x ?Shouldn't it be the port the service targets

Comment: yes, but can you share some code of how are defining the service and the deployment?

Comment: Your solution worked for what I was looking for. What I am trying to do is setup a FTP service which can be accessed using the ports from 50000 to 50100. The service needs these ports for data and the port 21 for control connections. I run my pod using hostNetwork: true meaning it binds on the host ip. But if I don't have the LB Service\IP, then I guess I would need to open these ports on all nodes since the pods could end up on different nodes ? . So I thought we could set it up as a service, but not sure if my approach is right